# How to delete the name of the controller in the URL with CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, url-rewriting, routes

I have urls that all contain /main/ in the url as it is my main controller.
I'd like to get rid of it.

I understood in the User Guide that the routing class will only re-route my URL, not hide a part of it (it is segment 1 according to their docuementation).
Thus, I've found this:

```
$route['(:any)'] = "auth/$1";
```

But I have 404 errors (That's the only modification I made to routing.php)

I believe I'll have to do it in the .htaccess, but I don't know what should be the syntaxe for that. For now, my .htaccess is this one:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    SetEnv MAGIC_QUOTES 0
    SetEnv PHP_VER 5
# For security reasons, Option followsymlinks cannot be overridden.
#   Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
    Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

I am using several controllers and my links are similar to this one :

Thanks

Comment: Cant help if you dont post both htaccess and routes.php and tell us exactly what you want. Routing goes first througt htaccess and then trough routes.php settings so you need to check htaccess first. Normally you only need to have htaccess remove index.php from your uri's. Also in your example you route all controller calls to your auth controller but you also say you want it to the main controller?

Comment: There is nothing what I can see in htaccess that would cause an unexpected 404. So you should be able to achieve what you want with routes.php. Can you explain what youre after a little more specific and how you built your uri's and controllers? The more you work with CI the less you will need routing is my experience, as you can use the intentional structure to build your controllers. (URI: Controller/Function/Parameter(s)) then you only need to have your default controller (main in your case) have the index function show the sites main page)

Comment: Thanks well actually I would like to go from those kind of url : website.com/Controller/Function/Parameter(s) to website.com/Function/Parameter(s) at least for my main controller (for the other one, such as blog, admin ... that's ok, I'd like to keep it).
So if I shouldn't do anything in the .htaccess file, what should I do in my routes.php ? I tried "$route['(:any)'] = "auth/$1";" but  when doing so, I get a 404 error when clicking on my links ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $route['blog'] = 'blog';  // seem stupid but otherwise the (:any) route below will send it to main
  $route['blog/(:any)'] = 'blog/$1'; // to have blog cotroller work
  $route['blog/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'blog/$1/$2';
  // repeat for other controllers

 $route['(:any)'] = "main/$1";
 $route['(:any)/(:any)'] = "main/$1/$2"; // if you use other uri parameter
 $route['default_controller'] = 'main'; // to have your main page work...
```

And put before this directive all calls to other controller as this will prevent all other controller calls.

Comment: Thank You !
So if I have 1000 controllers, I should do that 1000 times ? What is my main controller (and some others) have something like 3 or more arguments ? should I use /$1/$2/$3 ... everytime ?
I tried to access main/news/24 with and without that line : $route['(:any)/(:any)'] = "main/$1/$2";
I can't see any difference, is this line necessary ?

Comment: No definitely not (even though i never think you would have 1000 controllers in an app). Another  solution could be to either hardcode the main controller functions to route to main/(function) in routes or htaccess, then you dont need to do anything with the other controller uri's!

Comment: @MilesM. Say your default controller only contains the index function and all other pages have other controllers with their corresponding URI names, then you dont need ANY routing except the default. But now you built your app with main doing lots of things...

Comment: Hmm I see, which would be the best practice ? So for now, I just addes 30 lines, 3 for each controllers and I removed main/ from any href. It seems to work fine though. Now, let's say I want to rewrite uri again, changing the ID of a news (that I passed through the url to my function) by its title, is that the same process ? Because this time, both ID and titles are made dynamically. Maybe that's too far away from the original topic, I just want to know where to look.
Anyway, thank you very much for your help CI Jedi !

Comment: @MilesM. I guess the best solution is to just forward the rewritten news uri to the controller and let your news model find the corresponding id for you? To route this you would need to hardcode each article (NOT dynamic!)

Comment: AIE .. ok I'll see that another day. Thus, while making those changes, I'm facing a difficulty: I have a controller called "news" as it manages the news in the admin section, and a function, in the "main" controller that handle le review of a news by the front-user .. so now, when I try to access main/news/ID, I'm redirected to news/id, which lead to the admin section (of course it is protected and you need a password). Can I deal with that, or should I change either my function or my controller ?

Comment: @MilesM. Well a messy solution is of course to add another route to alter the name of your news controller. You just can"t have two pages with the same uri (ie news AND main/news routed to news). I would rethink my controller naming/structure before its too late! It gets terrible to debug with messy routing after a while and beutifully simple with little or no routing. Keep it simple!!

Comment: Thank You, I'll rename that function then :)